# PHP Register Form redirect to new page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

Im working on my loacalhost server on Mac and have a site that has a Register form using PHP. I intend to open a new Welcome page when the user submits the form.

The PHP code is:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
ob_start();
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
        header('Location: /welcome.html');
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("User Successfully Added")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

When the Submit button is clicked, it actually saves to user the the DB (it populates the table row in PHPmyAdmin), but then it stays on the register page while displaying the message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Stephen/Sites/tidy_map/register.php:61) in /Users/Stephen/Sites/tidy_map/register.php on line 73

With Line 73 being: header('Location: /welcome.html');

Comment: The warning speaks for itself and your question will be closed accordingly. Get rid of the echos.

Comment: Sorry But im not sure what that means and thought i could get some help

Comment: You can't echo out data then do a header redirect. Comment out your echo statements and see if it works.

Comment: Did you Google the warning?

Comment: Pass a parameter to the new url instead and on the page check to see if the parameter exists, if so, then do the echo, don't echo with the redirect

Comment: I commented out the echo statements but the same occurs

Comment: Then, you most likely have a byte order mark, or your included file is erroring out. Or.... you've HTML/JS etc. on top of what you posted and haven't shown us.

Comment: what is on line 61 and 73?

Comment: You can set `window.location.href` in your `<script>` element you echo out.

Comment: Also make sure there is no white space or blank lines at the start or end of your script.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: @tadman That comment is just so pleasing to look at. The synergy of colors from the links, the text body, _and the contents_ is beautiful. But, what's bad in some coding practicing? I learned PHP when I built similar stuff myself. My advice to OP: take these mentioned things **seriously** from the beginning, you will learn them in no time, but _don't_ be afraid to do heavy lifting yourself.

Comment: @JánosWeisz Practice is great, but please don't do it with people's important personal information and passwords. If you want to know how to write a proper authentication system, look at good examples, not tutorials that gloss over important issues. A good place to start is [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com/) which goes into more technical detail.